# React: can I use `key` outside of lists?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/young-fog-cpjg15?file=/src/App.tsx

I have a React app with a table of items and a sidebar in which the user can edit the selected item. The input fields are [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). The values in the table *should not update until the input is blurred*, which is why the input uses a local `value` instead of simply `<input value={item[field]} />`.

Of course, `value` should be *initialized* as `item[field]`. The problem: `setState` doesn't accept a dependencies array like other Hooks do, so I don't have a way to tell React the difference between the input value changing and the selected item changing (the latter of which should reset `value` to `newItem[field]`).

I was able to solve this by adding `key={item.id}` in the parent sidebar component, which resets the lifecycle of the `<Input>` component it contains. This is different from how `key` is usually used, though.

**Is this usage of `key` okay, or is there a more idiomatic way of solving this?**

Answer (score 0):

I should have Googled harder before asking this; leaving it up in case it helps someone else. The new React docs say this is ok: https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useState#resetting-state-with-a-key